# Email signature with HTML - Image moves after initial setup

Tags: html, email, signature

I'm making an email signature with images. I used a free online tool for the base html code, and then edited out advertisements etc, and changed it to my liking. I am having a peculiar issue - I have the image set to be on the right-side of the page, and when I first apply the signature to outlook, it works perfectly fine. But for some reason, once I try to create a new email after the first one has sent, the image which should be on the right side of the page goes over to the left side. Here is the code regarding the image..

```
<DIV class=main_html style="MAX-WIDTH: 800px; DIRECTION: ltr" align=right><IMG 
alt=sidebar src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/LINKHERE" align=right> </DIV>
```

Please note that I have changed the url to an invalid one purposely to protect privacy - the actual url I use is correct and working.

Then there are quite a few &nbsp, and a table below containing a small logo image, and text (If that is required I will happily add it in).

I have tried to change the Max-width of the div - I also changed the div to align right, and the image - these all worked the FIRST time and then after that it scooted right back over to the left side of the screen to my dismay.

Thanks in advance for your input, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong formating, misplaced and missing some `"`

```
<div class="main_html" style="max-width: 800px; direction: ltr;" align="right"><img alt="sidebar" src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/LINKHERE" align="right"></div>
```

Comment: Rendering in email clients is pretty inconsistent. You can try to add `style="float: right;"` to both `div` and `img` if it helps. Or alternative version with table `<table width="100%"><tr><td align="right"><img src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/LINKHERE"></td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Outlook omits all the contents inside the "style" tag for the signatures. But also you should check the missing " here:

```
... align=right ...
```

Both align tags are missing the quotes.